# Add TFS Custom dropdown field which uses existing users

Tags: tfs

To customize agile template in TFS, I am using witadmin tool. With this tool we can customize fields dropdown fields like this -

```
 <FIELD name="Severity" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity" type="String" reportable="dimension">
        <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
          <LISTITEM value="1 - Critical" />
          <LISTITEM value="2 - High" />
          <LISTITEM value="3 - Medium" />
          <LISTITEM value="4 - Low" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
        <DEFAULT from="value" value="3 - Medium" />
      </FIELD>
```

Is there any way with which I can create a custom dropdown field which is prepopulated with all active TFS users the way AssignedTo field gets populated with list of users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE and VALIDUSER rules:

```
<FIELD name="Severity" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity" type="String" reportable="dimension">
  <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
  <VALIDUSER /> 
</FIELD>
```